# Al intentar ejecutar comandos con adonis JS, aparece Error: Cannot find module '<ruta>\ace'

Tags: javascript, adonisjs

Tengo un problema con la instalación (creo, estuve investigando un poco). Resulta que cuando estoy instalando este framework según como dice la documentación y cuando intento ejecutar comandos ya de adonis, no me permite ejecutarlos y me dice lo siguiente:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Lucas\Proyectos\registro-asistencia\ace'
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: []
> }

*Node.js v18.16.1*

¿Cómo lo resuelvo?

Comment: la raíz de tu proyecto está en `registro-asistencia`? Si en esa carpeta está tu  `package.json`, corriste `npm install`?

Comment: Correcto, se encuentra en la raiz del proyecto. El problema ya lo pude solucionar resulta que era un problema de cache de npm, con un simple comando limpie el cache y tuve que rehacer el package.json. gracias por la ayuda saludos